# Is there any way to use a .txt as an input?

Tags: python

```
name = input("Whats your name?: ")
```

Can I use for example my .txt that is in the same directory on the input 'name'?
I tried the code bellow /

```
    with open(name.txt, "r") as file:
        file.readlines()
```

But its not working :(

Comment: What is not working? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Its just not doing anything, its just there, after I put that function with open[...], it just give me to enter text on the 'name' input

Comment: Besides your question is unclear, does your .txt file contains multiple lines?

Comment: just 1 line, with my name.

Comment: no empty strings

Comment: @Mordecai911 You just read the text via `file.readlines()`. You don't process it in any form. What did you expect?

Comment: and what should I do? whats the correct grammar for it?

Comment: `name = file.read()` should do the work. And get rid of the `name = input("Whats your name?: ")`.

Comment: `print(file.readlines())`

Comment: The name of the file should be a string: `open('name.txt', "r")`

Comment: I forgot, to put the ' ' here in this question, but its still not working, the function is not using the name.txt in the input :(

Comment: Your problem is really not well explained. Please post in the question if you are getting any kind of error, if you are getting a wrong output than expected and please post the exact code that you are using

Comment: ```filename = "name.txt"
name = input("Whats your name?: ")
with open(filename, "r") as file:
     file.readlines()
```

Comment: There it is, but its not working.. its still letting me to put the input, I have to put myself something in that input, because it doesn't automatically take the first line from name.txt

Comment: Please [edit] the question with that information, don't use the comments. And I really don't understand what surprises you. You have the line `name = input()`, that asks for input from the user. If you don't want it - remove it...

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you want exactly. I think you want the variable `name` to be a name taken from a textfile.

```py
with open("name.txt", "r") as file:
   name = file.readline().strip()

print(name)
```

It works by opening up the file `name.txt` for reading as text, then it reads the first line, `strip()` is used to remove any spaces or newlines, and it is stored in the variable `name`.

There is no need to call `input()`.

Be sure to read the tutorial on [input and output](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).